# Progress bar is not visible on App loading in android

Tags: android

This is my HomeActivity clas

```
 class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(), BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    
        @Inject
        lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel
    
        var isAppInforeground = true
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            AndroidInjection.inject(this)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
            navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
            loadFragment(HomeFragment())
            if (getGrantStatus()) {
                homeViewModel.apply {
                    saveDailyHourly()
                    observe(stateLiveData, ::onChangeState)
                }
            } else {
                startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS))
            }
    
        }
    
        override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            var fragment: Fragment? = null
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.navigation_home -> fragment = HomeFragment()
                R.id.navigation_monitor -> fragment = MonitorFragment()
                R.id.navigation_profile -> fragment = ProfileFragment()
            }
    
            return loadFragment(fragment)
        }
    
        private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment?): Boolean {
            //switching fragment
            if (fragment != null) {
                supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit()
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    
       
    
       
    
    
        /**
         * check if PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission is aloowed for this application
         *
         * @return true if permission granted
         */
        private fun getGrantStatus(): Boolean {
            val appOps = applicationContext
                .getSystemService(APP_OPS_SERVICE) as AppOpsManager
            val mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(
                AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS,
                Process.myUid(), applicationContext.packageName
            )
            return if (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_DEFAULT) {
                applicationContext.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            } else {
                mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED
            }
        }
    
        
        private fun onChangeState(state: State) {
            when (state) {
                is Loading -> {
                    // Sho Progress Bar
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Loading ..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                is LOADED -> {
                    // Hide Progress Bar
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    progressBar1.visibility = View.GONE
                }
                else -> {
    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:text="@string/title_home"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorNavIcon"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorNavText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="24dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:indeterminate="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have one view model class where i am calling saveDailyHourly method which take some 1 minute to load data i am trying  show loader i.e progress bar i have progress bar in xml by default i kept visible and when function loaded i am hiding it but when i launch app progress bar  is not showing i don't know what is the issue please help me what i am doing wrong .

Comment: try with progressBar1.visibility = View.VISIBLE on is loading section  and before the section starts

Comment: I dont konw  i tried progressBar1.visibility = View.VISIBLE but it is not showing

Answer (score 1):

in your code you are using only setting visibility to `GONE`, never showing with `VISIBLE` param. I think it should be placed in `onChangeState`

```
    private fun onChangeState(state: State) {
        when (state) {
            is Loading -> {
                // Sho Progress Bar
                progressBar1.visibility = View.VISIBLE // ADD THIS
                Toast.makeText(this, "Loading ..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            is LOADED -> {
                // Hide Progress Bar
                Toast.makeText(this, "Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                progressBar1.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            else -> {

            }
        }
    }
```

your `progressBar1` is visible on start as set by XML, but you are saying that it isn't visible. just inspect `onChangeState` calls, put `Log.i("onChangeState", "state:"+state);` line in method and check what it gets (looks like it gets `LOADED` state very quickly after starting `Activity`, so it hides `progressBar1` and never shows again)

Comment: I tired this code but its not coming at all i am not getting call back in Loading state in view model when function start i am calling  stateLiveData.postValue(State.Loading)

Comment: for (i in generateSequence(0) { it }) {      } i tired to add infinite loop in view model  try to see progress bar its not showing .